# How to use/refector nested promises?

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I'm using Promises in my TypeScript application to fetch my data from the best source possible. First localStorage should be tried, then an API call to my server. I'm not sure if this approach is the best at all, so comments are welcome.

```
loadData(): Promise<void> {
    return this.loadFromLocalStorage()
        .catch(() => {
            this.loadFromApi();
        })
}

loadFromLocalStorage() : Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if( !this.isSupported(() => localStorage) ) reject("Localstorage is not supported");
        data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('metadata') );
        if( !data || !data.date ) {console.log("no data"); reject("Not all data was present");}
        this.setData(data, false).then(() => {resolve()});
    });
}

loadFromApi() : Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<{date?:string,ddi?:number,stoff?:number}>(this.apiUrl+'meta.json')
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.setData(data, true).then(() => resolve());
        },
        () => {
            reject("API call failed");
        });
    });
}

setData(data, saveToLocal: boolean) : Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let promises: Promise<Pilot|void>[] = [];
        if (data.ddi) {
            promises.push( this.pilotService.getById(data.ddi).then(ddi => this.ddi = ddi) );
        }
        // There's more promises by the way, this is simplified
        Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Now I know there's some error here, but the main questions is: **how do I handle returning a promise inside a promise?** Is it even neccessary? I tried searching for a solution to flatten things out, but couldn't find one that takes into account that some actions are not to happen when the first promise (fetching from localStorage) fails.

Comment: Soluce is `async/await`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your improved code in the answer you posted is good, but it can still be made more concise and maintainable:

1. Note that async functions always return Promises. You're basically only wrapping each function body in a Promise to get them to return one, but this is unnecessary if you make the encompassing function async.
2. Instead of using booleans to indicate success/fail status, I used rejected Promises instead as it's more idiomatic in JavaScript and with async/await you can write this in an intuitive "synchronous" fashion (`throw` in an async function causes the returned Promise to reject)
3. When you can return a value indicating success, I strongly suggest doing so - whether or not you actually use it doesn't matter much, but in case you do need it it can simplify existing code.
4. You can use `try/catch` when using `await` as a method of handling `await`ed Promise rejections, it makes the code very intuitive
5. Style nitpick: Your use of semicolons is inconsistent. Either semicolons or no semicolons is fine, but you ought to stick to one or the other. It improves readability and if anyone else touches your code they won't have any questions about when to use semicolons.

---

```
async loadData(): Promise<void> {
    try {
        return await this.loadFromLocalStorage(); //await this one to catch rejections
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message); //handle error
        return this.loadFromApi(); //await or don't await this one, same result
    }
}

async loadFromLocalStorage() : Promise<Pilot[]> {
    if( !this.isSupported(() => localStorage) ) throw new Error("Not Supported");
    //if JSON.parse errors, the promise will also convert the exception to a rejection
    data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('metadata') );
    if( !data || !data.date ) throw new Error("No Data");
    //this function returns a promise resolving with whatever `setData` resolves with
    //or rejects if `setData` rejects
    return this.setData(data, false);
}

//this one still needs to return a promise as it wraps a .subscribe()
loadFromApi() : Promise<(Pilot|void)[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<{date?:string,ddi?:number,stoff?:number}>(this.apiUrl+'meta.json')
            .subscribe( data => {
                resolve(this.setData(data, true)); //resolve with the data
            },
            reject); //if there's an error, just reject with the error
    });
}

async setData(data, saveToLocal: boolean) : Promise<(Pilot|void)[]> {
    let promises: Promise<Pilot|void>[] = [];
    if (data.ddi) {
        promises.push( this.pilotService.getById(data.ddi).then(ddi => this.ddi = ddi) );
    }
    //Promise.all will reject if any one of the inner promises rejects
    //To circumvent this, add a .catch() to the inner promises
    return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

This code follows a more idiomatic usage of Promises and async/await. Each function either *resolves* with a meaningful value if it succeeds or *rejects* with a meaningful error if it fails for any reason.

Because of async/await, any errors also cause the rejection to "bubble up" the stack all the way to the caller, i.e. if something goes wrong in `loadFromApi()` the Promise will *reject* with an Error, which then causes `loadData()` to also reject with that same error, exposing it to the function that called `loadData()` and allowing you to encapsulate error handling for this data API (any errors caused by any internal function can "bubble up" to the entry point `loadData()` and be handled as you wish)

Answer (score 1):

lets draw your api

```
           loadData
          / 
         / 
        /
       *
loadFromLS ------* loadFromApi
       \               /
        \             /
         \           /
          \         /
           \       /
            \     /
             *   *
            setData
```

So you api is one directional, (nothing goes up)

---

But your loadData is unnecessary here, I'm also suggesting this kind of api, its not tested, see it as pseudo implementation

> `waterfall([this.loadFromLS(this.loadFromApi), this.setData]`
>
> So waterfall accepts array of promises, which are called after each other and passing passes the result of previous to next promise

See full pseudo demo below

```
    function waterfall (...args) {
        const promises = [].concat(...args)
        const first = promises[0]
    
        let firstPromise = first()
        for (let i = 1; i < promises.length; i++) {
            firstPromise  = firstPromise.then(() => promises[i])
        }
        return firstPromise
    }

    class MyClass {
        loadData(): Promise<any> {
            const data = waterfall([this.loadFromLS(this.loadFromApi), this.setData])
            return Promise.resolve(data)
        }
    
        loadFromLocalStorage(replacement) {
            return function (): Promise<void> {
                if (!this.isSupported(() => localStorage) {
                    return replacement && replacement()
                }
                const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('metadata'))
                return Promise.resolve(data)
            }
        }

       loadFromApi() : Promise<void> {
           return this.http.get<{date?:string,ddi?:number,stoff?:number}>(this.apiUrl+'meta.json')
       }
    
        setData(data) : Promise<void> {
            let promises: Promise<Pilot|void>[] = [];
            if (data.ddi) {
                promises.push( this.pilotService.getById(data.ddi).then(ddi => this.ddi = ddi) );
            }
             // There's more promises by the way, this is simplified
            return Promise.all(promises)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Three changes were made in order to fix this:

- `resolve()`/`reject()` was replaced by `resolve(true)`/`resolve(false)`
- `return` was called after `resolve`/`reject` to stop further execution
- `.then()`/`.catch` were replaced by `async`/`await`

Here's my final code:

```
loadData(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if( await this.loadFromLocalStorage() ) {
            resolve();
            return
        }
        await this.loadFromApi();
        resolve()
    });
}

loadFromLocalStorage() : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if( !this.isSupported(() => localStorage) ) {resolve(false); return;}
        data = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('metadata') );
        if( !data || !data.date ) {console.log("no data"); resolve(false); return;}
        await this.setData(data, false);
        resolve(true);
    });
}

loadFromApi() : Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        this.http.get<{date?:string,ddi?:number,stoff?:number}>(this.apiUrl+'meta.json')
            .subscribe( async data => {
                await this.setData(data, true)
                resolve(true);
            },
            () => {
                resolve(false);
            });
    });
}

setData(data, saveToLocal: boolean) : Promise<null> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let promises: Promise<Pilot|void>[] = [];
        if (data.ddi) {
            promises.push( this.pilotService.getById(data.ddi).then(ddi => this.ddi = ddi) );
        }
        // There's more promises by the way, this is simplified
        Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Returning a promise that wraps an async function is actually rather redundant. I think three of these four functions could easily be converted to just an async function to begin with - remember that async functions always return promises so they fit this case perfectly. If you'd like me to demonstrate what I mean I can write up an answer.

Comment: Great! Please see my posted answer :)